# thumbnail image gallery jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, image-gallery

i am trying to make a thumb gallery.
       **structure:**

- one container to display big images
- another container which is having 3+ groups each having 3 options of radio button.
- on selecting any of the option from radio button that respective image should be display in the big container.
- by selecting any of the three options from each group the images should display in the big container but all images should remain in the container itself.
  i have tried this in jquery [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/FJqEL/3/) as i am a beginner in this can any one suggest the correct way.

[image]

thumb images is coming from a '/images/thumbs' folder 
 big images is    coming from a 'images/big' folder